# Liquibase formatted sql precondition tableExists

Tags: mysql, migration, liquibase, preconditions

Liquibase xml based changeset block:

```
<preConditions>
  <not>
    <tableExists tableName="alarm" schemaName="public"/>
  </not>
</preConditions>
```

How it should be in "liquibase formatted sql"?
Official documentation of Liquibase give only xml based

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
--preconditions onFail:HALT onError:HALT
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = 'alarm';
```

The `expectedResult` is a String in liquibase and the evaluation will do a String comparsion. So whatever your sql returns needs to match exactly (including case sensitivity).

You can also check the unit test class [FormattedSqlChangeLogParserTest](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/test/groovy/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParserTest.groovy) for further examples.

Comment: I have been looking for this all day, thanks a ton